# Поднять сайт на Centos

Tags: centos, vps

Добрый день у меня вот такой вопрос. Нужно поднять сайт на Centos уже установлен VPN.
Какие действия нужно делать, может кто-то уже практиковал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установить Apache, PHP, MySQL. Посмотрите [здесь](http://centos.name/?page/howto/LAMP/). В общем-то в гугле по запросу "[Установка LAMP Centos](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+LAMP+Centos&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&client=opera&hs=230&rls=ru&q=%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+LAMP+Centos&oq=%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+LAMP+Centos&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.1896.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.XwKTjfISH80&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=97469e7423a287a6&biw=1276&bih=729)" даст вам желаемое.

[Здесь](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) найдете готовую сборку с инструкцией по установке.

Comment: Не проще ли из репозитария поставить?

Comment: Да, сейчас дополню!

Comment: LAMP это линупс+апач+мускул+похапе для тех, кто ниасилил поставить по частям. CentOS уже стоит, осталось доставить Apache2, далее по мере надобности. Не фокусируйтесь на **з**борках.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но сами знаете, с теми проблемами в формулировках вопросов, вы и не заметите очередной вопрос, как установить PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Ну, не знаю, не знаю. XAMPP был в свое время очень знаменит дефолтными паролями. [Да и сейчас тоже неплохо](http://www.google.com/search?q=bugtraq+XAMPP)